# how to add a subdomain with another server ip in cpanle(API) with php script

Tags: php, subdomain, cpanel

I have a cpanel account. I wants to add a subdomain having ip (it points to another server) with the help of php script.

does any one have any idea?

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Check this link : http://www.wiredstudios.com/php-programming/setting-up-wildcard-dns-for-subdomains-on-cpanel.html

Answer (score 0):

Well first you should grab the [XML-Api wrapper for php](https://github.com/CpanelInc/xmlapi-php) - it makes things a lot easier.

Then check the [api reference](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/ApiDocs/Api2/ApiSubDomain) for the methods you'll need.

Comment: thanks
i have checked it but here is no option to set ip address of other server for subdomain.

If you have any idea please let me know.

Comment: You'll have to use the apis ZoneEdit::fetchzone and ZoneEdit::edit_zone_record for that.

Comment: Hmm I just realized that ZoneEdit::add_zone_record may be better suited for your needs (sorry for the confusion).

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.cpanel.net is the official documentation for the cpanel api. Unfortunately, it really is hard to get around, at least for me it was.

You will need to read up on the api yourself though since I know of no implementation of your issue.